# I want to render a "flow chart" diagram, where arrows go between symbols (from one box to another) and not between boxes

Tags: equations, symbols, flow-charts

I want to render a diagram that's like a flow chart, but where arrows go between a symbol in one box to a symbol in another box (as opposed to having an arrow that points from one whole box to another whole box). I want to change the code to render the image below (excuse the ugliness):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{equation} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node (get_c) [equation] {$C \leftarrow A + B$};
\node (get_d) [equation, below of=get_c] {$CX - Y \rightarrow D$};
\node (get_x) [equation, below of=get_d] {$X  \leftarrow  F + G$};

\draw [arrow] (get_c) -- (get_d);
\draw [arrow] (get_x) -- (get_d);


\end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image: target image]

What I am getting with the code above is this:

[image: what I have so far]

Comment: Edited. I hope this makes it easier for people to offer their input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrices to access the expressions in  the equation, and place some `{}` at the right places after `&` just like in ordinary arrays of the same purpose. `calc` can be used for the relative alignment. I didn't know if you want to have all the nodes terminate at the same horizontal positions, so I added both options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,fit,matrix,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm,
    equation/.style={rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum
        height=1cm,text centered, draw=black},
    marrow/.style={thick,-stealth},
    tmat/.style={matrix of math nodes,column sep=0pt,anchor=west,
        nodes={minimum width=0pt,minimum height=0pt,anchor=center,inner xsep=0pt}}]
  \node  [tmat] (get_c) {C&{}\leftarrow A + B\\};
  \node (get_d) [below=of get_c.west,tmat] {C&X&{} - Y \rightarrow D\\};
  \path let \p1=($(get_d-1-2.west)-(get_d-1-1.west)$) in
  node (get_x) [below=of get_d.west,tmat,xshift=\x1] 
     {X&{}  \leftarrow  F + G\\};
  \draw[marrow] (get_c-1-1) -- (get_d-1-1);
  \draw[marrow] (get_x-1-1) -- (get_d-1-2);
  \path foreach \X in {c,d,x} {node[fit=(get_\X),equation]{}};
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
  \node  [tmat] (get_c) {C&{}\leftarrow A + B\\};
  \node (get_d) [below=of get_c.west,tmat] {C&X&{} - Y \rightarrow D\\};
  \path let \p1=($(get_d-1-2.west)-(get_d-1-1.west)$) in
  node (get_x) [below=of get_d.west,tmat,xshift=\x1] 
     {X&{}  \leftarrow  F + G\\};
  \draw[marrow] (get_c-1-1) -- (get_d-1-1);
  \draw[marrow] (get_x-1-1) -- (get_d-1-2);
  \path node[fit=(get_c)(get_d)(get_x)](F){}
  foreach \X in {c,d,x} {node[fit=(get_\X-|F.west)(get_\X-|F.east),equation]{}};
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For complex things you can use [Tikz packages](https://www.ctan.org/search?phrase=tikz)
Also, I higly recommend to use editors like [Mathcha](https://www.mathcha.io/) to create this complex images, tables, scripts, 3d images, etc.

So, there are steps to do:

1. Open Editor for free.

[image]

2. Create the model as you want like the example image below

[image]

3. Export to LaTeX

[image]

4. Add the required packages to your document

   \usepackage{physics} 
   \usepackage{amsmath} 
   \usepackage{tikz} 
   \usepackage{mathdots} 
   \usepackage{yhmath} 
   \usepackage{cancel} 
   \usepackage{color} 
   \usepackage{siunitx} 
   \usepackage{array} 
   \usepackage{multirow} 
   \usepackage{amssymb} 
   \usepackage{gensymb} 
   \usepackage{tabularx} 
   \usepackage{booktabs} 
   \usetikzlibrary{fadings} 
   \usetikzlibrary{patterns} 
   \usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur} 
   \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
5. Add the script of your content between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`

[image]

6. In less than 5 minutes you added what you want, results in the image below.
   [image]

Example fullcode:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{physics}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathdots}
\usepackage{yhmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}


\title{Title1}
\author{Author1}
\date{May 2020}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{every picture/.style={line width=0.75pt}} %set default line width to 0.75pt        

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.75pt,y=0.75pt,yscale=-1,xscale=1]
%uncomment if require: \path (0,300); %set diagram left start at 0, and has height of 300

%Straight Lines [id:da4873436163497318] 
\draw    (169,102) -- (169,160) ;
\draw [shift={(169,162)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;
%Straight Lines [id:da7827018032544013] 
\draw    (282,103) -- (282,161) ;
\draw [shift={(282,163)}, rotate = 270] [color={rgb, 255:red, 0; green, 0; blue, 0 }  ][line width=0.75]    (10.93,-3.29) .. controls (6.95,-1.4) and (3.31,-0.3) .. (0,0) .. controls (3.31,0.3) and (6.95,1.4) .. (10.93,3.29)   ;

% Text Node
\draw (57,46.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\frac{a}{b} +\sqrt[3]{a+b} +\int ^{a}_{b} dx+\overbrace{a-b}^{n+1} +\wideparen{ABC} +\widehat{ABC} +\Uparrow H_{2} 0\Uparrow $};
% Text Node
\draw (117,170.4) node [anchor=north west][inner sep=0.75pt]    {$\frac{a}{b} +\sqrt[3]{a+b} +\int ^{a}_{b} dx+\overbrace{a-b}^{n+1} +\wideparen{ABC}$};


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```